# PHP: checkbox-isset always returns true

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, checkbox

In my form (which i'm submitting using jQuery's ajax() via POST) i've got the following checkbox (to check if the new user should have admin rights):

```
<form action="../inc/new_user.php" id="new_user_form">
    Username:<br><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br><br>
    Email:<br><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br><br>
    Password:<br><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br><br>


    <!-- here's the checkbox -->
    Admin: <input type="checkbox" name="admin" /><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

I then post the values (all other fields work perfectly fine, just the checkbox doesn't):

```
$( "#new_user_form" ).submit(function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var $form = $( this ),
        username = $form.find( "input[name='username']" ).val(),
        email = $form.find( "input[name='email']" ).val(),
        password = $form.find( "input[name='password']" ).val(),
        admin = $form.find( "input[name='admin']" ).val(),
        url = $form.attr( "action" );

      var posting = $.post( url, { username: username, email: email, password: password, admin:admin } );

      posting.done(function( data ) {
        $( "#message_dialog" ).empty().append( data );
        $ ("#message_dialog" ).dialog({
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

and this code is used to get the values in PHP:

```
$user_username      =   $_POST['username'];
$user_email     =   $_POST['email'];
$user_password      =   $_POST['password'];
if (isset($_POST['admin'])) {
    $user_admin = 1;
} else {
    $user_admin = 0;
}
```

But when I echo $user_admin, I always get "1", regardless of the state of the checkbox. This is weird, since I was told many times that if the checkbox is unchecked, the $_POST value won't be set.

I also tried using the value-attribute on the input element, and compared it in PHP. none of my methods worked, which drives me insane right now.

Note: I'm setting my php variable $user_admin to either 0 or 1 to store it as a TINYINT in my database (MySQL). 1 meaning "Yes, the user is admin" and 0 meaning "No, he's not admin".

Please tell me what is going wrong here.

Comment: There is no value attribute for the checkbox, you are trying to pull val() from it and sending it via jQuery - hence you get nothing.

Comment: This because you're establishing the variable manually, thus there will always be an admin return in your php post side. If you wan't to get it correctly, don't create each one of those `var`s. Just simply get your form data as `var $formData = $form.serializeArray()` then just use `$.post( url, $formData)`

Comment: Please see: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ && http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `admin = $form.find( "input[name='admin']" ).val()` will always return `'on'`, since your not getting if it's checked or not. One way to fix this would be to change the end to `admin = $form.find( "input[name='admin']" )[0].checked`, which would give you `true` |or| `false`.

Second, because you're passing the data as `admin: admin`, Your server side will ***always*** have `isset($_POST['admin'])` as `TRUE` |or| `1` because, technically, it is set. When you manually send the data through as `admin: admin`, you're telling server side, "Hey, there is a  key here named `admin` and i'm sending with a value for a JS variable named `admin`!" Thus, it `isset`.

To avoid this, you can use jQuery's [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) to get the values same as if the `form` had been submitted normally (`aka, not using e.PreventDefault`).  So your rewrite could be as simple as:

```
$( "#new_user_form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this),
        $data = $form.serializeArray(),
        url = $form.attr( "action" );

    var posting = $.post(url, $data);

    posting.done(function(data) {
        $( "#message_dialog" ).empty().append(data).dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This also means, `if (isset($_POST['admin']))` will work as you expect it too.

---

**Tip**: Keep in mind, that you can always add data to a form's serialized array simply by adding a `name/value object` to the data gathered. For example, from the above we have `$data = $form.serializeArray()`. If you wanted to add another value to the data gathered from the form then you would simply:

```
$data[$data.length] = { name: 'bob', value: 'hello world' };
```

Thus now providing another value server side read as: `$_POST['bob']`!

Answer (score 3):

You probably want a boolean telling you if the checkbox is checked or not :

```
admin = $form.find( "input[name='admin']" ).is(':checked'),
```

and then check it in PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['admin']) && $_POST['admin']) {
```

Comment: on the jquery end, it works. I alerted the admin variable, returned true or false depending on the state of the checkbox.
On the php site, the post variable also has the same value as the JS one, but when putting it into my $user_admin avriable, it doesn't

Comment: Then it should work on the PHP side as well, just figure out what to check for, could be you have to check for the string "true", or convert it to a boolean with `(boolean)$_POST['admin']`etc ?

Comment: okay, fixed it by checking the value of the $_POST var with =="true".

Comment: But because `admin` is passed through as data always, then `isset($_POST['admin'])` will always be true, thus negating its use, unless OP sends form data through as k/vP's, as form data is meant to be sent.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_POST['admin'])) {
    $user_admin = 1;
} else {
    $user_admin = 0;
}
```

this means whether the `$_POST` have the checkbox value
and in your page checkbox always in the `$_POST` but with different value of its state
and you can try this

```
if ($_POST['admin']) {
    $user_admin = 1;
} else {
    $user_admin = 0;
}
```

Comment: problem is that I sent the raw data of the checkbox rather than the state. Using that would probably mean I'd have to change some jQuery as well...

Comment: ah,sorry, I forgot the jquery admin = $form.find( "input[name='admin']" ).is(':checked')

Answer (score -1):

That is because you are sending the value as a empty string (see example below), try using `strlen($var)===0` to check if its empty.
This piece of code:

```
  var posting = $.post( url, { username: username, email: email, password: password, admin:admin } );
```

will send the data like this:

```
$_POST['username'] = "foo";
$_POST['email'] = "bar";
$_POST['password'] = "foobar";
$_POST['admin'] = ""; // empty string! Because it has no value
```

Comment: nope. when I var_dumped the POST array, I always got
$_POST['admin'] => "on" str_len = 2
or sth. similar